# convexity of the objective function

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, trace

My objective function is of the form,

$
 \text{minimize} ~~Trace(XAX'B) ~~ \text{such that X is a doubly stochastic matrix}
$

But, unfortunately, my optimization program says it is non-convex (cvx package in Julia).  I am not very sure why it is not convex, any idea ?

Comment: It depends. What are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: A and B are positive matrices (I mean elements are positive, not PSD)

Comment: Suppose that $B=I$, and $I$ is a positive but not PSD matrix.  Your objective can be non-convex in that case.